# Angular, ngClass, using function to evaluate element class - performance and best practice approach

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular-components, ng-class

Im useing ngClass over button element which get function , code is about:

initiate formGroup and the function

```
gentrateForm() {
    this._formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        remarks: '',
    });
}
    getButtonClasses() {
    const inpulValue = this._formgroup.get('remarks');
    if (inpulValue.value) {
        return `some css classes`;
    } else {
        return `other classes + disabled class`;
    }
}
```

}

finally ant the component html

```
<button
 [ngClass]="getButtonClasses()">
Delete
</button>
```

My questions:

- Is it better (performance point of view) - using the ngClass logic at the template itself or
  better move it to the class?
- Is it any other way I should implement it? other paths?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's better to separate the template and the code.
Your case:

```
<input formControlName="remarks" #remarks/>....

<button
 [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3': remarks.value}">
  Delete
</button>
```

If class is only one, it's easier:

```
<button
 [class.class1]="remarks.value">
  Delete
</button>
```

Comment: Since got several class cant use [class.class..]